# Добавить в JOIN значение по умолчанию

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем доброе время суток, есть несколько таблиц

**Content**

```
id |title|Author_Id |
---|-----|----------|
 1 | asd | 2        |
---|-----|----------|
```

**Author_Content**

```
Author_Id |Content_id |
----------|-----------|
     2    |     1     |
----------|-----------|
```

**Author**

```
Id   |Name |
-----|-----|
2    |Павел|
```

*Столбцы не имеющие отношения к вопросу были опущены, для экономии места.*

Собственно вроде бы все понятно, *Content* - таблица с каким-то контентом; *Author_Content* - таблица соотношений id контена -> id автора; *Author* - id Автора -> его имя.

Я дергаю данные вот таким запросом:

```
SELECT
    t2.id as `txt_id`,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( t2.show_time ) as `date_end_time`,
    1 as index_id,
    `type_id`,
    `content_type_id`,
    `title`,
    `annonce`,
    `content`,
    t2.title as title,
    t1.Author_Id as Author_Id,
    t3.Name as AuthorName
FROM
    `Content` as t2
JOIN `Author_Content` as t1 ON
    t2.id = t1.Content_id
JOIN `Author` as t3 ON
    t1.Author_Id = t3.Id
WHERE
    t2.status = 1
    AND t2.content_type_id != 14;
```

Запрос отрабатывает хорошо, возвращает все что нужно, кроме ситуации, когда нет в какой то таблице данных, увы сайт который достался по наследству, подразумевает что в **Author_Content** может и не быть соотношение id контена -> id автора, тогда запрос возвращает пустой результат.

Если точнее то не выполняется вот это условие в запросе:

```
t2.id = t1.Content_id
```

**Собственно сам вопрос:** помогите составить запрос так что бы в случае отсутствия записи в **Author_Content** возвращалось какое то дефолтное значение, например *-1*; я так понимаю там должно быть что то вроде If но не знаю если честно как его подружить с JOIN

Comment: Используйте `Content LEFT JOIN Author_Content LEFT JOIN Author`. В полях при отсутствии данных будет `NULL`.

Comment: Да спасибо большое, это работает, но тут есть такая беда, этот запрос я использую для интеграции со сторонним софтом, а он не умеет обрабатывать коректно NULL ( там логика такая тупая ) поэтому надо вернуть что то отличное от NULL или 0, я сейчас пытаюсь копать в сторону IFNULL в MySQL - Может у вас будут по этому поводу какие то соображения?

Comment: *надо вернуть что то отличное от NULL или 0* Ну оберни значения соотв. полей в `COALESCE(field_name, if_null_value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо пользователю [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) за ответы, но сделал немного по своему, все-таки решил через IFNULL

```
SELECT
    t2.id as `txt_id`,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( t2.show_time ) as `date_end_time`,
    1 as index_id,
    `type_id`,
    `content_type_id`,
    `title`,
    `annonce`,
    `content`,
    t2.title as title,
    IFNULL(t1.Author_Id,-1) as Author_Id,
    IFNULL(t3.Name,'N/A') as AuthorName
FROM
    `Content` as t2
LEFT JOIN `Author_Content` as t1 ON
    t2.id = t1.Content_id
LEFT JOIN `Author` as t3 ON
    t1.Author_Id = t3.Id
WHERE
    t2.status = 1
    AND t2.content_type_id != 14;
```

Comment: *все-таки решил через IFNULL* Напрасно... IFNULL - это всего лишь версия COALESCE со строго 2 параметрами.